# How to attach images to a vsix file?

Tags: vsix

I'm trying to customize the startpage for the Visual Studio 2010. I have download the Custom Start Page Project Template from Microsoft to do it.

```
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f655a5dc-1a2d-4eca-b774-76c352c03b87
```

Now on the my customized start page project, there are a couple of images that I want to embed in the project, so that I can give someone else my vsix file and they can install it along with all the images. That way they don't have to download all the images, and link them to the location of all the images on their computers. I have tried all the suggestions here and on the msdn forum, but none of them are working for me. Here is what I have tried:

- Create a folder called Images on the root folder
- Add all the images in there
- Set the build action of each image to `Resource` (I even tried Embedded Resource with no luck)
- Rebuild the project

One more thing, I could see the image on the design process. However, when I run the project by hitting F5 (it will run on the experimental instance), the images do not show up at all.

I'm at my wit's end now, I don't know what to do or what I should do. Do anyone have this problem before and find a way how to fix it ? Thank you.

Comment: a) Click on an image and set "Include in VSIX" enabled in properties window. Maybe this hepls you? b) you can base64 images, would that help you somehow?

Comment: @Erti-ChrisEelmaa: It won't let you have both set to "Resource" and "Include in VSIX". In order to be "include in VSIX", it needs to be set to Content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click on the Image and set`Include in VSIX` to `True`.   You'll also need to make sure the `Build Action` is set to `Content`.  This will cause the image to get installed into the Visual Studio plugin folder.

To get the path to the installed image, let's assume you have a file, `a.jpg` and it's in the folder `images`, which is at the root level of your Package project.

```
public string GetImageFullPath(string filename){
    return Path.Combine(
            //Get the location of your package dll
            Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location,
            //reference your 'images' folder
            "/images/",
            filename
         );
}
```

Then to get the full path to your image:

```
 GetImageFullPath("a.jpg");
```